# Couldn't access mongo-express from Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-machine, mongo-express

I am trying to carry out some experiments with Docker, MongoDB, and mongo-express.

Here was what I did:

```
docker network create my-network 
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --network my-network --name my-mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mongo 
docker run -d -p 8081:8081   --network my-network --name my-mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME="ambiance" -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="my-mongo" -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME="admin" -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD="pass" mongo-express
```

No error message was received apparently.

However, when I entered the address "localhost:8081" on Chrome, the page displayed an error message saying:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the admin username and password on the database, but then you use the 'normal' user environment variables to try to log on. Instead of ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME and ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD, you should use ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME and ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD, like this

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081   --network my-network --name my-mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME="ambiance" -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER="my-mongo" -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME="admin" -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD="pass" mongo-express
```